# Media Query targting wrong element?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to make my `#logo` element disappear once the screen gets smaller than 670px. It works in that the logo disappears but it takes my navigation with it for some reason. Why is my nav ul disappearing?

**The Code:**

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url(img/grey-bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
  min-height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}
header nav ul {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -28px;
  margin-right: 5%;
  z-index: 3;
}
header li {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Cabin Sketch', cursive;
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 30px;
  z-index: 3;
}
#logo {
  height: 75%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 670px) {
  #logo {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Jovial Entertainment | Home</title>
    <link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch'rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/JOVIAL-LOGO-TEXT.png" id="logo"/></a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>VIDEOS</li>
          <li>ABOUT</li>
          <li>PHOTOS</li>
          <li>CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you changed it to `display: none`, it's not there on the page any more, therefore there's nothing to take up the space where it once was, so your nav is moving over to where the logo was. Try `visibility: hidden` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Was driving myself nuts over that haha

Answer (score 0):

You have negative margin on your navigation, so once you remove the logo your navigation just goes above the top of the screen. You need to set margin top of your navigation to zero in your media query.